# Getting string from date picker dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker

I am using [the example from the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

From the method

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
```

I want the string "Mon, Sep 14, 2014". How do I get it? Ideally I really want  "Mon, Sep 14, 2014 10:30PM" but I can't find a combined date and time picker.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go date time combined.

This is no meant to be mean just that you said you were having trouble finding one.

how to find it :  http://bit.ly/1doSxEf

Which one I use:

https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way 
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
 Time chosenDate = new Time();
 chosenDate.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
 long dt = chosenDate.toMillis(true);
 CharSequence strDate = DateFormat.format("KKK MMM dd,yyyy", dt);
 // mow use  strDate..
}
```